# How does Ownership in manual sharing a single record work?

Tags: administration, security, sharing-rule, manual-sharing

I was asked a question: If A and B are two users and A manually shares a record he owns to User B and then he leaves the organization. Now a third User comes and gets the Ownership of the record in the organization, will A still be able to have access to the record? (See/Edit)?. Also does manually sharing a record transfer ownership to the new user with whom record is shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in [Manual Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.granting_access_to_records.htm&type=5):

> If a user transfers ownership of a record, Salesforce deletes any manual shares created by the original record owner, which can cause users to lose access. When account ownership is transferred, manual shares created by the original account owner on child records, such as opportunities and cases, are also deleted.

I think your question may be misworded: If A has left the organization, they no longer have access. Likewise, B will no longer has access after the record is transferred to C, because A shared the record with B. Sharing a record with a user does not grant Ownership, as only one user can own a record at a time. However, the user's managers will also have Full Control (the permission granted by being the Owner), assuming the Share Using Role Hierarchy is set for a given object; standard objects, like Account, automatically behave this way.

Comment: could you answer this too? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391508/how-to-prevent-user-from-re-clicking-a-button-to-submit-input-fields-until-api-s